# If I believe that AAVE is a legitimate dialect of English, am I a linguistic prescriptivist or a descriptivist?

Tags: dialects, african-american-vernacular-english

Or maybe there is a third categorization I should use, such as "linguistic [inclusivist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusivism)"?

I believe that hypercorrections like "This is a secret between you and I" and "Whom is he?" are incorrect insofar as the speaker considers himself to be speaking in a formal, non-slang context.

However, I do believe that African American Vernacular English is a culturally legitimate form of English, so I disagree with extreme prescriptivists who want to quash out the dialect.

Does this make me a moderate prescriptivist? Or a hard descriptivist? Or something else?

Comment: This question is kind of all over the map. Are you asking about the definition of *dialect*, the definition of *AAVE*, or the definition of *prescriptivist*? At any rate, even the Wikipedia article on AAVE says that it is a dialect right in its very first sentence. What else could it possibly be?

Comment: @Reg "What else could it possibly be?": if you asked Dr. Strunk, for example? "Wrong.". The (OP's) question is, if you *don't* say "wrong*, are you necessarily a descriptivist?

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, that's exactly what I'm asking. You'll hear a lot of people, like schoolteachers and armchair linguists, saying things like "He be chilling" is normatively incorrect.

Comment: It *is* incorrect.  It should be, "He be chillin'."

Comment: @Jim, you're such a condescendin' prescriptivis'.

Comment: No, I don't think that AAVE is a culturally legitimate form of English. But I don't think that any other dialect is either. Dialects ARE.  They don't require any form of approbation by some self-appointed cultural czar.

Comment: (1) there are no descriptivists; there are only prescriptivists. They imagine they are fighting a gigantic battle, but in fact they're simply hallucinating. (2) You can be anything you want to be, whatever you believe. (3) @Oldcat is right -- lects exist and nobody's in charge of legitimating them. Even considering the question is insulting. Do you have a birth certificate for your idiolect of English? Are you **sure** that it's a legitimate dialect of English? Can you prove it?

Comment: @DanBron: S&W wrote a style-guide to help students hone their writing. S&W did not set out to document the various dialects of English.

Comment: Aren't prescriptivists about something that's not a dialect, but a strange animal called "standard?"